# separating the records in a kdb table

Tags: kdb

There is a table with a column that I would like to break into multiple records. For example

```
q)tab:([]a:1 2 3;b:(`a;`$"b c";`d);c:2 3 4)
q)tab
a b   c
-------
1 a   2
2 b c 3
3 d   4
```

There is a space between `b` and `c` in the second entry of column `b`, I would like the table to become

```
a b c
-----
1 a 2
2 b 3
2 c 3
3 d 4
```

I  tried

```
" " string vs exec b from tab
```

but didn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `b` is the column with multiple entries per row, you can count each value and expand the corresponding row entries accordingly. Then `ungroup` like Terry mentioned should work.

```
q)t:([]a:1 2 3;b:(`a;`b`c;`d);c:2 3 4)
q)![t;();0b;{x!(enlist({(count each x)#'y};`b)),/:x}cols t]
a   b    c
------------
,1  ,`a  ,2
2 2 `b`c 3 3
,3  ,`d  ,4
q)ungroup ![t;();0b;{x!(enlist({(count each x)#'y};`b)),/:x}cols t]
a b c
-----
1 a 2
2 b 3
2 c 3
3 d 4
```

**EDIT**: Realised after your comment that the input is different. I think this is what you want.

```
q)t:([]a:1 2 3;b:(`a;`$"b c";`d);c:2 3 4)
q)ungroup update`$" "vs'string b from t
a b c
-----
1 a 2
2 b 3
2 c 3
3 d 4
```

Comment: hey sorry, my bad. `(b c) is one symbol in the table. do you know how I should separate?

Answer (score 1):

You would normally do this using `ungroup`:

```
q)ungroup([]a:1 2 3;b:((),`a;`b`c;(),`d);c:2 3 4)
a b c
-----
1 a 2
2 b 3
2 c 3
3 d 4
```

Comment: this table already exists. I think it is `(b c)